# Laravel and React Native can work separately?

Tags: php, reactjs, laravel, react-native

I am having a little confusion trying to understand what's going on.

Let me explain, I have a web application built with Laravel 6. Also, I am building a mobile app using React Native separately, I want to connect the app and fetch the data of the web application.

I have routes inside my web.php file of Laravel. The thing is I don't know if I need to create new routes inside my api.php file so I can connect my React Native App. Do I have to use both files with the exact same routes or what?

This is my web.php file:

```
Route::get('/', function () {
    return view('welcome');
});

Route::get('/storage', 'ProductController@index');
Route::get('/storage/{id}', 'ProductController@show');
Route::post('/product', 'ProductController@store');


Auth::routes();

Route::get('/home', 'HomeController@index')->name('home');
```

Do I have to make the same routes but inside my api.php file so React Native can connect to my web application?

Thanks in advance for your help.

Answer (score 1):

For your React Native App you should usually have some sort of JSON API for data fetching.

Guessing from your routes you are returning Laravel Views from your controller. If so, you can't reuse the data used for views without getting messy.

If you don't want to split your routes/controllers you can detect if the request came from the mobile app (for example with a token in the request header) and after that use a different response in your controllers based on where the request came from. But this is not a scalable approach and controllers become unmaintainable.

What I suggest is to have separate routes and controllers for your web and mobile app.  And extract the common business logic(e.g. DB Queries, data processing) in Service classes and use them in both controllers.

I work with a similar tech stack(Laravel MVC/React Native) on a large project and so far using separate routes and controllers is a solid choice.

---

Edit:

You can use a plain class for a service. And make it specific for some kind of functionality.
A simple example of a service.

```
class PostService {
       //this method has common logic that 
       //is used by both API and WEB controllers
       public function make($request) {
         //validate the request
         //create the post $post
         //send emails, notifications, etc
         return $post;
     }
    }
```

And your web controller might look like:

```
class PostController(Web) { 
   public function store(Request $request) {
      //you can also store this in the constructor
      $postService = new PostService(); 
      $post = $postService->make($request);
      return view('post.created')->with(['post' => $post]); 
  }
}
```

Your API controller might look like this:

```
class PostController(API) { 
   public function store(Request $request) {
      //you can also store this in the constructor
      $postService = new PostService(); 
      $post = $postService->make($request);
      return response->json(['post' => $post], 200); 
  }
}
```

Basically, you extract some common functionality into a class. Your logic code will be in your service (e.g. custom logic, custom validation, post creation, email and notifications) and the controllers only move data from the service and model it out in a type of response. (in this case, view or json).

For queries and model related work you can also use the repository pattern in Laravel.

I found some useful articles here:

- [Service Class](https://m.dotdev.co/design-pattern-service-layer-with-laravel-5-740ff0a7b65f)
- [Repository Pattern in Laravel](https://medium.com/employbl/use-the-repository-design-pattern-in-a-laravel-application-13f0b46a3dce)

Hope this helps!

Comment: So you mean having 2 controllers, one that works with the web.php routes and another one using api.php? And so, returning json data using the api.php controller?

Comment: Yes. You should create different sets of controllers and routes for web and mobile app. You could use the app.php routes for the mobile app.

Comment: Structuring the Laravel app this way will help with separating the flow for both web and mobile. As your app grows you will do different actions in both(e.g. different authentication flow, different data for the same route - less data on mobile app). This can create duplicate code, but extracting common logic(queries, data processing) in a service or repository helps a lot.

Comment: When you say “service”, what do you mean exactly?